# What is the relationship between a function and a value?

Tags: javascript, theory

What is the relationship between a function and a value? I thought that a function was a type of value; however, functions both contain values (arguments) and return values too.

---

*I'm (obviously) new to programming, and want to ensure that I have a solid conceptual foundation as I move my way through JavaScript.*

Comment: Then get a book and read. I suggest reading JavaScript: The Definitive Guide.

Comment: The funny thing about JavaScript is that both of your statements are correct!

Comment: What do you mean by "functions [...] contain values"?

Comment: This might be a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I recommend this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Answer (score 4):

Functions do things.  Variables hold values (data).

A function can accept data as arguments.  A function can also return data, but does not have to.  Consider this function which just adds two numbers together:

```
function addNumbers(numberA, numberB) {
    var total = numberA + numberB;
    console.log(total);
}
```

This is a function which accepts two arguments.  Within the function's code block, those arguments' values are assigned to the variables `numberA` and `numberB`.  The function's code creates another variable, `total`, and assigns the value of `numberA` added to the value of `numberB`.  The function then calls another function, `console.log`, with the value of `total` passed in as an argument.

Now, the function can also return values.  Let's modify this function a bit:

```
function addNumbers(numberA, numberB) {
    var total = numberA + numberB;
    return total;
}
```

If you were to call this function now, you get back the value of `total`.  If I were to run this:

```
console.log(addNumbers(5, 5));
```

You would see `10` in the console.  My number literal values were passed as arguments to `addNumbers`.  The function did its work and returned to me the value of its `total` variable.  This value is now passed in as an argument to `console.log`.

If that isn't crystal clear yet, then please read other tutorials online before continuing.

Now, in JavaScript functions are just like anything else.  You can assign them to variables as well!

```
var newAddNumbers = addNumbers;
console.log(newAddNumbers(5, 5)); // Also returns 10 in the console
```

When you type:

```
function someFunction () {
```

This is no different than:

```
var someFunction = function () {
```

The function itself is assigned to the variable `someFunction`.  In our original example, the function itself was assigned to `addNumbers`.  So yes, function is a type just like number, object, boolean, etc.

Comment: _"...is no different than..."_ - Well, the difference may not matter for this question, but there _is_ a significant difference.

Comment: @nnnnnn, Can you elaborate?  I got into this discussion on another thread awhile back, and that was the conclusion we came to.  I'll see if I can dig it up.

Comment: Try calling the function on the line _before_ it is defined - you'll find that it works with the first declaration style but not with the second. Also something like `var func = makeFunction();` (where `makeFunction()` returns a reference to some other function) can only work the second way. No need to repeat any further explanation here when there are [quite a few questions about this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+function+declaration+style), for example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname).

Comment: @nnnnnn, Yes, that makes sense.  Functions defined as `function someFunction` are hoisted with the variable, whereas with `var someFunction = function`, the variable is hoisted but as with anything else, setting it isn't.  I've never thought about that!

Answer (score 2):

If I have a function:

```
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

`add` is a function. All functions are values; I can place them in a variable or pass them as an argument, for example.

`a` and `b` are arguments of `add`, but the function has not been called, so they do not have values. Similarly, the function has been called, so it has no return value.

When I call the function:

```
add(1, 2);
```

The function executes with `a` and `b` initially set to `1` and `2` respectively for that invocation.

If I call it again with different arguments:

```
add(3, 4);
```

Then this time `a` and `b` are initially set to `3` and `4`; however, these `a` and `b` not only have different values than the last time; they really are different variables. Every time you call a function, the arguments are essentially variables, which are local not only to that function but to that *invocation* of that function.